# Can the order in which broker's plugins execute be defined?

Tags: activemq-classic

I need to implement 2 filters that fit in the *amq:discardingDLQBrokerPlugin* category, and I need one to be executed before the other.

I can implement the two filter's logic in one class, but since the business logic is very different, I would prefer two.

I add the filters using two different plugins: *com.filter.FilterAPlugin* and *com.filter.FilterBPlugin*. The filter execution order follows a "last defined first executed" logic.

Example: In this broker configuration

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false" schedulerSupport="true">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
    <amq:plugins>
        <amq:discardingDLQBrokerPlugin dropAll="true" dropTemporaryTopics="true" dropTemporaryQueues="true" />
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="com.filter.FilterAPlugin" />
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="com.filter.FilterBPlugin" />
    </amq:plugins>
</amq:broker>
```

Filter added in *com.filter.FilterBPlugin* is executed first.

Does the order in which the *beans* are declared defines the order of execution of the filters? I can't find documentation about this in the apache MQ web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*BrokerService* uses Chain of Responsibility pattern, so execution order is defined by the object initialization order.